# Keyboard close force when call Webservice

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard

i have a chat view contain `tableView` and `textView`, i'm using `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` for manage keyboard, after each send message request i get list again (call webService), when keyboard is appear and i send message keyboard closes very quickly and then opens, i can't find where is happening, I try disable `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` for this class, i don't have any view End Editing code in my `viewController`. i want to keyboard appear always As long as the user close keyboard.

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Share your code block, that will help to locate problem.

Answer (score 0):

I find problem, when I show loading View for update list my keyboard closed, I have a gif for loading view and I using SwiftGifOrigin for animating gif. I remove startLoading method when get list from server and now keyboard in show.